# wordpress nginx rewrite to wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I want to create dockerized Wordpress with nginx that will use /kokpit instead of /wp-admin I'm using nginx:latest container with default config. And declared my server block for Wordpress like below

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/localhost.key;

    server_name dimidia.dev.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/stderr_dimidia debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/stdout_dimidia;

    location /media
   {
     rewrite ^/media/(.+) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/$1;
   }

    location /
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

   location /kokpit
   {
     rewrite ^/kokpit(.*) /wp-admin$1;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_pass dimidia_php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

However when I reach to /kokpit files like load-scripts.php are returning 404 instead of scripts, and I cannot reach any php files inside kokpit (all are returning 404) big question is: why?